# Android Flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I need to combine two flavors that are available in my project and each flavor is divided for different aspects i.e one flavor for one functionality. All I need is to combine the two flavors such that i can have two functionalities in one build. Is there any method to combine two flavors? If there plz help me..thanks in advance.

```
 productFlavors {

       flavor1{
//for one functionality
        }

        flavor2{
//for second functionality
        }
        flavor3{
//for third functionality
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of research got an answer to my problem.The solution is as follows:

sourceSets{

```
    flavor3{
        java.srcDirs 'src/flavor1/java','src/flavor2/java'
        res.srcDirs 'src/flavor1/res','src/flavor2/res'
    }
}
```

By doing so i can combine two flavors into single functionality as i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Flavours are used to create versions of the same app (as the name indicates).

If you want to split your application into features it will be better to separate them into android library modules.

Here is a guide of how to do this:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html